# Adding item to Flatlist by getParam

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

**DIET** (MAIN PAGE)

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       foodList: [],
             };
     }

      render() {

          return (

               <View style={{ flex: 1, top: hp("12%"), height: hp("100%") }}>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('FoodCreate')}>
                   <Text>Press to insert Food Name</Text>
                </Button>
                  <FlatList
                    data={{this.props.route?.params?.foodList}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key.toString()}
                    renderItem={(data) => (
                      <ListItem itemDivider title={data.item.food} />
                    )}
                  />
                </View>
```

**FOODCREATE**

```
export class FoodCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      food: null,
      foodList: [],
    };
  }

  submitFood = (food) => {
    this.setState({
      foodList: [
        ...this.state.foodList,
        {
          key: Math.random(),
          name: food,
        },
      ],
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Diet", {
      foodList: this.state.foodList,
    });
  };
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon
                name="arrow-back"
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
              />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Add Food</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon
                name="checkmark"
                style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.submitFood(this.state.food);<-----------
                }}
              />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", top: hp("3%") }}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Food Name"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            style={styles.inptFood}
            value={this.state.food}
            onChangeText={(food) => this.setState({ food })}
          />
        </View>
```

Hey everyone, so this is how this app should work: when I start Expo it brings me to the `Diet` screen, from there I press the `Button` to add a new food to the `Flatlist`, once I get sent to `FoodCreate` screen I type in the TextInput the name of the food and when I click the checkmark in the header it should send me back to `Diet` and display in the `Flatlist` the name of the food I typed, and so on. When I run the app it gives me the following error: `this.props.navigation.getParam is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
this.props.route.params.foodList
```

The parameters are passed via the route.params prop, with Navigation v5 the getParams option is not there

Comment: thank you for answering, now it gives me the error: `undefined is not an object (this.props.route.params.foodList)`

Comment: oh ok so Diet is the first screen ? in that case do a null check like this so  this.props.route?.params?.foodList, so it wont throw an error in first render

Comment: thank you, now the error doesn't show anymore, but when I type the Food and tap the checkmark icon it brings me to the Diet screen but nothing shows on the list.

Comment: ok you have passed the state just after updating it, so do the navigate as a callback to the setState in submitFood this.setState({//urchanges},()=>{//navigate from here})

Comment: could you give me the example you are talking about, I'm generally new to programming

Comment: something like this   this.setState({
      foodList: [
        ...this.state.foodList,
        {
          key: Math.random(),
          name: food,
        },
      ],
    },()=>{      this.props.navigation.navigate("Diet", {
      foodList: this.state.foodList,
    });});

Comment: if you are using functional components, you can refer this sample https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen

Comment: I tried that but now it doesn't navigate to the Diet screen when I tap the checkmark

Comment: Never mind I inserted it wrong, it worked!!!!, thank you for your help